# I'm trying to use input to output to a filename

Tags: input, filenames

I'm trying to use input to variable to create a file using the input the filename
The only examples I've seen are print(input)

I'm new to Python but trying to write a functional program

thanks

Comment: I can't parse your first sentence sorry: you're trying to accept a filename as input, and store that in a variable, then use that variable to create an output file? And then write something to that file?

Comment: Maybe it could be better done this way.  I can create the file and once I'm done amending the file I would like to change the filename via input I'm trying to automate creating a config file with a specifying the filename from the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This is nice beginning for you

```
def create_file():
    fn = input('Enter file name: ').strip()
    try:
        file = open(fn, 'r')
    except IOError:
        file = open(fn, 'w')
```

Comment: did you call the create_file function?

Comment: No, what function  ?

Comment: Did you mean import os ?

Comment: I posted a def named create_file as above about my answer. You could call it in your py file, your ide (pyCharm or Terminal) will ask you for a input.. if you use python2 it will be raw_input and for python3 it will be input

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can use the `open()` function to create a file (assuming it will be a text file).

The documentation for it is located [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Using your input variable to create the file, you could do it like so:

```
file = open(input, 'w+')
```

This will give you a file object which you can write lines to using the `write()` function.

Comment: I'm not just looking to create a file but to create it after typing the name

Comment: If you are using Python 2 then you should use `input = raw_input()` which will wait until a person types something into the console and presses the enter key. For Python 3 you should use the `input()` function instead.

Comment: I understand the write function but I want to use keyboard input for the name

Comment: Yes that is what the raw_input() and input() functions do as I mentioned in my comment. Your Python version will change which function is best to use.